# Is it possible to upgrade windows 7 to the ultimate(from professional) edition without reinstalling

Tags: windows-7

I want to upgrade a windows 7 professional installation to windows 7 ultimate. Is that possible without reinstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/01/windows-anytime-upgrade-wau-for-windows-7-official-prices-list-and-details/) but it doesn't appear to get around the having to do some sort of install though it is supposed to keep your settings.

This post [The Windows Anytime Upgrade Experience for Windows 7](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windows7/pages/the-windows-anytime-upgrade-experience-for-windows-7.aspx) at the Windows Team Blog walks you through the process.

Comment: Ah this is exactly what i need.

Comment: Upgrade finished in less then 10 minutes!!

Comment: That's great news Niek. Now we know that it actually works and doesn't take very long.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed only with  Windows Anytime Upgrade but this is only available from October the 22nd, thus the release. At least, I got a notification (error!) pointing this way

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving up versions, I don't see why not. You can probably do an anytime upgrade too.

You just won't be able to go across bits, so 32-bit to 64-bit (or the other way) is out of the question.

Comment: Do you also know how to do this? Can i just enter a new key or do i to download the ultimate edition put it on a dvd and use it for the upgrade.

Comment: you need the media + a key & yes, you have to run setup to do an upgrade